# ZSTD compression with tar and --ultra 22 on Mac OSX and homebrew (with progress bar)

Tags: terminal, progress-bar, tar, zstd

I want to be able to compress a file or folder, and see the progress of said input in the terminal. This is my current progress so far, but I have two issues with it:

1. This should be possible without an interim step of creating the tar file
2. The gauge is immediately jumping to 100% and stays there until it finishes.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit script if any command fails
set -e

# Check that two arguments are passed
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <directory_to_compress> <output_file>"
    exit 1
fi

# Check if required commands are available
for cmd in du tar zstd pv; do
    if ! command -v $cmd &> /dev/null; then
        echo "Error: $cmd could not be found. Please install it."
        exit 1
    fi
done

DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS="$1"
OUTPUT_FILE="$2"

# Create the tar file
tar -cvf "$OUTPUT_FILE.tar" "$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS"

# Compute the size of the tar file in bytes
SIZE=$(du -sh "$OUTPUT_FILE.tar" | cut -f 1)
SIZE_BYTES=$(echo $SIZE | awk '/^.*[0-9\.]+[Kk]?$/{printf "%.0f", $1*1024}; /^.*[0-9\.]+[Mm]?$/{printf "%.0f", $1*1024*1024}; /^.*[0-9\.]+[Gg]?$/{printf "%.0f", $1*1024*1024*1024};')

# Compress the tar file with zstd using pv for progress
pv -p -s ${SIZE_BYTES} "$OUTPUT_FILE.tar" | zstd -T0 --ultra -22 > "$OUTPUT_FILE.tar.zst"

# Remove the intermediate tar file
rm "$OUTPUT_FILE.tar"

echo "Compression completed successfully. Output file is $OUTPUT_FILE.tar.zst"
```

I heavily researched this before posting, and I have checked the following sources before:

- The older Stack Overflow question [Is there a way to see any tar progress per file?](https://superuser.com/questions/168749/is-there-a-way-to-see-any-tar-progress-per-file) does not apply, as I need $1 as input for the script
- [Apparently this is how to use Zstd with tar if anyone else was wondering](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21959517) (I cannot use this approach, as I want to be able to use --ultra)
- [ZSTD example with dialog](https://gist.github.com/Eddy-Barraud/1583532910760f2942133b03863fd758)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to pipe the `tar` via [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) to `zstd`. If you know in advance how much data you're going to pipe, you can even have it give a percentage progress.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output of `tar` directly into `zstd`, and let `zstd` progress notification tell you how much data was processed so far, as well as compression efficiency projection.

It won't give you a `%` completion, because it doesn't know how much data is left to process, but it will generate enough activity on screen to tell that it's progressing through the input, which is a more comfortable "live" return signal, in contrast with the default "no signal at all, maybe the process is stuck, who knows" that most unix tools tend to default to.

Comment: If you pipe it via `pv` you can get a progress bar, if you know the total size in advance!